# How to check if titles are an exact match in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

In our application we have screen with multiple header titles (.tasktable__header.tasktable__header--title) and i want to verify these titles. The code i had didn't do the job, because it allways looked at the first available item.

```
verifySubIncidentTitleMatch(incident: string): void {
       cy.get(this.#subDossierTitle).each(ele => {
           expect(ele.text()).to.equal(incident);
       })
   }
```

But i want to store the header titles in array and then compare them, but i don't know how.

Here is the HTML. The table classes are in a div 'top20' (first screenshot)
And the 'tasktable__header--title is within the thead of that class.

[image]

[image]

Comment: how are you expecting to target more than one when you're trying to pull an `id` when IDs should only be used once?

Comment: Can you add some HTML for the tables?

Comment: Have you studied the docs of the  "get" query operator already: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get They have some nice examples there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to store the title texts in an array, use a `.then()` callback to do the conversion and use `include` on the resulting array.

```js
verifySubIncidentTitleMatch(incident: string): void {
  cy.get(this.#subDossierTitle)
    .then(elements => Array.from(elements).map(element => element.innerText))
    .should('include', incident)
}
```

You could also apply `Array.some()`

```js
verifySubIncidentTitleMatch(incident: string): void {
  cy.get(this.#subDossierTitle)
    .then(elements => Array.from(elements).map(element => element.innerText))
    .should(titles => {
      expect(titles.some(title => title === incident)).to.eq(true)
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks! The Array.some solution is working just fine! The test still fails but now it's up to the developers to make sure the application is working as required ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I would say instead of using `.each()` you just want to select one of the titles with `.eq()`.

```js
cy.get(this.#subDossierTitle)
  .eq(1) // use 1 if it's the 2nd title
  .should('have.text', incident)
})
```

You will have to work out which one is correct, perhaps trial-and-error if it's not obvious from the HTML.

Comment: I would also suggest adding `data-cy` attribute to make the title unique.

Comment: not only that but documentation suggests targeting data attributes and not IDs or classes

Comment: The selector used may well be a data attribute, you have no way of knowing. @darthvader you are confusing ids with [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

Comment: @A.A.Qadosh you're right about the data-cy but that's not possible here. There can be 1 subincident or x subincidents. We try to incorporate as much data-cy labels as possible.

Answer (score 4):

You have another option, that is to say use [oneOf](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof) assertion - this effectively matches many-to-one, i.e many element texts to one incident string.

I'm assuming for the moment that you just want to know that one of them matches up, and don't really care which one.

```js
verifySubIncidentTitleMatch(incident: string): void {

  cy.get(this.#subDossierTitle).should(els => {
    const texts = [...els].map(el => el.text)
    expect(incident).to.be.oneOf(texts)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know oneOf, so we will give this a try.